# Is there an expression or idiom to express that your brain has temporarily stopped working because you've been overwhelmed by something?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request, informal-language

I am looking for an informal idiom or expression to imply that my brain has stopped working temporarily because say I have dealt with a heavy math question or I have gone through an overwhelming process or I have run across an astounding view etc.

When your phone crashes or acts up frequently and operates with delay, you can simply say:

> - My cellphone **keeps freezing**.

I was wondering weather we can say:

> - My brain has frozen.

Once I have heard:

> I've got a brain freeze.

But I couldn't find any web source to back it up. Please let me know about it any any more fitting and natural idiom or expression.

Comment: Did you look in a [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brain-freeze)?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea what is the colloquial / casual structure in everyday English. Is it "**suffer a brain freeze**" or "**having a brain freeze**"?

Comment: Be careful because a 'brain freeze' can be a term for a headache caused by very cod drinks or ice cream.

Comment: Still I have no idea about what I asked Michael! ;)

Comment: "Gobsmacked" (chiefly British) means "stunned speechless", so it works for a beautiful view, but not for a difficult math question.

Comment: After a long time @Michael Harvey, one more question came to mind! May I ask you whether "(I'm having / I've got) a brain freeze" and "**(I'm having / I've got) a mental block" mean the same and any of these construction can be used interchangeably in either case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'brain freeze' can be what happens when you have temporarily forgotten something. A rather vulgar variation is 'brain fart'. 'I'm suffering a brain freeze' is more formal, 'I'm having' one is less formal, and 'I've got' one even less formal. You could also say 'my brain has frozen' or 'has seized up'.

Another meaning of 'brain freeze' is 'severe but brief pain in the head induced by the consumption of very cold food or drink'. Generally the context will tell the reader or listener which meaning is intended.

[Brain freeze (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brain_freeze)

[Brain fart (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brain_fart)

Comment: I wonder whether "brain freeze" is being progressively drafted into service as a euphemized alternative to "brain fart." I was under the impression that it really referred only to the headache.

Comment: I've *never* heard brain freeze used to describe a brain fart, only for headaches caused by eating or drinking cold things.  Is this a regional usage?  I know Lexico cites it, but I want to know where Lexico got that information...

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use the term "my mind went blank" for a generic my brain has stopped working.

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/my+mind+went+blank)

It doesn't seem to quite fit your needs, though; it seems you're talking about a kind of mental exhaustion in your first example (dealing with a tough question), and a feeling of being overwhelmed in your second (seeing a fabulous view). For that second one I might use something like the term "I was at a loss for words", or "the beauty of the view overcame me and I was unable to even process it".